# How to send variables from Main to another method, then return a value back to Main method?

Tags: c#, console-application, return-value

I want to send the variables temperature and windSpeed to the ComputeWindChill method to find the windchill. Then return windchill back to the Main method to display the temperature, wind speed, and the temperature that includes the wind chill.

```
public class Program
{

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Random rnd = new Random();

        int temperature = rnd.Next(0,50);
        int windSpeed = rnd.Next(4,30);

        Console.Write("Temperature: {0}", temperature);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("Wind Speed: {0}", windSpeed);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("Temperature (including windchill): {0}", ComputeWindChill.windChill);

        ComputeWindChill(temperature);
        ComputeWindChill(windSpeed);
        } // end Main

        public double ComputeWindChill(int temperature, int windSpeed, double windChill)
        {
              windChill = 35.74 + 0.6215 * temperature - 35.75 * Math.Pow(windSpeed,0.16) +
                     0.4275 * temperature * Math.Pow(windSpeed,0.16);

        return windChill; 
    }
} // end class
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Error? Unexpected results?

Comment: `ComputeWindChill` returns a value but you are not capturing it.  It also takes 3 params (but seems like it should only need 2 since one is the result) the code only passes 1

Answer (score 1):

You can use **"out"** for getting back windChill value after calling method

```
public class Program
{
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
Random rnd = new Random();
int temperature = rnd.Next(0,50);
int windSpeed = rnd.Next(4,30);

Console.Write("Temperature: {0}", temperature);
Console.WriteLine();
Console.Write("Wind Speed: {0}", windSpeed);
Console.WriteLine();

// Not sure what you are trying to do here?
Console.Write("Temperature (including windchill): {0}",ComputeWindChill.windChill);

double windChill=0;

ComputeWindChill(temperature,windSpeed,windChill);

ComputeWindChill(windSpeed);
} // end Main

public static double ComputeWindChill(int temperature,int windSpeed,out double windChill)
{
      windChill = 35.74 + 0.6215 * temperature - 35.75 * Math.Pow(windSpeed,0.16) +
             0.4275 * temperature * Math.Pow(windSpeed,0.16);

return windChill; 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should mark `ComputeWindChill` as static. Otherwise you can't use it. Furthermore, you have to store somewhere the result of the method you call and then use it. As your code is, even it would be compliled withour errors, you call the method and you don't use it's result. Last but not least the method expects 3 parameters and you pass only 1.

Comment: And it requires 3 parameters instead of one. And return values is not used. And..

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I noticed it later and I added it. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You must change your method to this:

```
public static double ComputeWindChill(int temperature, int windSpeed)
{
    return 35.74 + 0.6215 * temperature - 35.75 * Math.Pow(windSpeed,0.16) +
         0.4275 * temperature * Math.Pow(windSpeed,0.16);
}
```

This would accept 2 parameters (temperature and windspeed) and would return a double with all the calculations. You should also notice that the method must be declared as `static` because you are calling it from another static method (`main`)

The call should be like this:

```
double windChill=ComputeWindChill(temperature,windSpeed);
Console.Write("Temperature (including windchill): {0}", windChill);
```

Another alternative is using `out` parameters. In this case, instead of the method "returning" a value,what it does is setting the value in the variable passed as `out` parameter:

```
public void ComputeWindChill(int temperature, int windSpeed, out double windChill)
{
    windChill= 35.74 + 0.6215 * temperature - 35.75 * Math.Pow(windSpeed, 0.16) +
             0.4275 * temperature * Math.Pow(windSpeed, 0.16);
}
```

Notice the `void` return paramenter, and the `out` keyword in the third parameter.

The call to this method is a bit different:

```
double windChill;
ComputeWindChill(temperature, windSpeed,out windChill);
Console.Write("Temperature (including windchill): {0}", windChill);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
 {

 Random rnd = new Random();

 int temperature = rnd.Next(0,50);
 int windSpeed = rnd.Next(4,30);

 Console.Write("Temperature: {0}", temperature);
 Console.WriteLine();
 Console.Write("Wind Speed: {0}", windSpeed);
 Console.WriteLine();

 //here you make a new double called windchill which will be equal to what your calculate windchill method returns 
 double windChill = ComputeWindChill(temperature,windSpeed)

 Console.Write("Temperature (including windchill): {0}", windChill);

 } // end Main

 //I removed your third parameter called windchill here because you do not know it yet, you are calculating it and make this a static method(read up on static methods - very important)
 public static double ComputeWindChill(int temperature, int windSpeed)
 {
      double windChill = 35.74 + 0.6215 * temperature - 35.75 * Math.Pow(windSpeed,0.16) +
         0.4275 * temperature *       Math.Pow(windSpeed,0.16);

 return windChill; 
 }
```

p.s. I'm typing on a phone

Answer (score 0):

You need to first understand how to define a function.
For example take your function.
In your function the temperature and windspeed are the arguments you wish to send to the ComputeWindChill function. And the you need a double value windspeed to be returned from the function.

So you define your function as

```
public static double ComputeWindChill(int temperature, int windSpeed)
{
    return 35.74 + 0.6215 * temperature - 35.75 * Math.Pow(windSpeed,0.16) +
     0.4275 * temperature * Math.Pow(windSpeed,0.16);
}
```

and while calling the above function, you should pass the arguments to the function, all at the same time and store the expected return value from the function.

```
double windChill=ComputeWindChill(temperature,windSpeed);
```